# Continiutity of a dense subset imply continuity of the set

Tags: real-analysis

I would like some help proving that if $f$ and $g$ are continous on $(a,b)$ and $f(x)=g(x)$ for every $x$ in a dense subset of $(a,b)$ then $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x$ in $(a,b)$.

Comment: What can you say about the set $(f-g)^{-1}(\{0\})$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S\subset(a,b)$ be the dense subset in the question.  Take any $x\in(a,b)$, and find a sequence $\{a_n\}$ in $S$ such that $a_n\to x$.  Such a sequence exists precisely because $S$ is dense in $(a,b)$.

Now, we know that $f(a_n)=g(a_n)$ for all $n$ because they agree on $S$.  We also know that $f$ and $g$ are continuous on $(a,b)$.  By continuity, we have:

$$f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(a_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}g(a_n)=g(x)$$

Comment: no i somewhat follow the first half of your argument though. i want to say there are finitly man points missing so who cares about them =)

Comment: @user70337: A dense subset does not necessarily miss only finitely many points.  It could miss many more than that.  I've finished the argument if you're interested.